# Adding additional field to registration form magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I've seen and tried a lot of tutorials that explain how to proceed but i've a problem, i need this change to be only on one of my two stores, this is a field that needed to be displayed only in my professional store not the other one. This field can prove to me that the customer is a real professional.

I've someone already have done this or know or to do, any help would be appreciate .

Comment: are you already added this field as customer attribute or you want overall process to do this

Comment: Not yet because i don't my other customers see it only professional one

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only on one store then you can check what store is active right now with:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

or by store code:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

So you can show this field only for customers from that store like this:

```
if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() === 1){ 
   //show field here 
}
```

**Another option** is to create child theme for one of your stores and extend it from main theme, so you can have two different templates with different set of fields.